# Member function template deduction isn't working

Tags: c++, function, pointers, templates

I'm writing a class that wraps a member function while allowing for type-erasure.

```
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
class FunctionWrapper;

template<typename Ret, typename...Args>
class FunctionWrapper<Ret(Args...)> {
   public:
   
   template<typename T>
    FunctionWrapper(T& object_reference, Ret(T::*function_ref)(Args...)) : 
        object_ptr(&object_reference), callable(&static_method<T, function_ref>)  {}

    private:
     typedef Ret (*callable_type)(void*, Args...);

     void* object_ptr;
     callable_type callable;

     Ret operator()(Args&&...args) {
        callable(object_ptr, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
     }

    template<typename T, Ret(T::*function_ref)(Args...)>
     Ret static static_method(void* object_ptr, Args...args) {
        T* obj = static_cast<T*>(object_ptr);
        return (obj->*function_ref)(args...);
     }
};

struct S {
    void add() {}
};

template<typename T, typename Ret, typename... Args>
auto static get_function_wrapper(T& object_ref, Ret(T::*function_ref)(Args...)) {
    return FunctionWrapper<Ret(Args...)>(object_ref, function_ref);
}

int main() {
    S s;
    const auto shallow_function = get_function_wrapper(s, &S::add);
}
```

But I'm receiving an error saying that the deduced `static_method` is not a `callable_type` which I don't understand.

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'FunctionWrapper<Ret(Args ...)>::FunctionWrapper(T&, Ret (T::*)(Args ...)) [with T = S; Ret = void; Args = {}]':
<source>:38:12:   required from 'auto get_function_wrapper(T&, Ret (T::*)(Args ...)) [with T = S; Ret = void; Args = {}]'
<source>:43:55:   required from here
<source>:12:40: error: no matches converting function 'static_method' to type 'FunctionWrapper<void()>::callable_type' {aka 'void (*)(void*)'}
   12 |         object_ptr(&object_reference), callable(&static_method<T, function_ref>)  {}
      |                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:25:17: note: candidate is: 'template<class T, void (T::* function_ref)()> static Ret FunctionWrapper<Ret(Args ...)>::static_method(void*, Args ...) [with Ret (T::* function_ref)(Args ...) = T; Ret = void; Args = {}]'
   25 |      Ret static static_method(void* object_ptr, Args...args) {
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
Execution build compiler returned: 1
```

I don't understand why this isn't working

Comment: And the reason why `object_ptr` is a fugly `void *`, instead of `T *`, would be what, exactly?

Comment: *wraps a member function while allowing for type-erasure*, You don't need a class for that: `std::function my_func = [&](){ s.add(); };`

Comment: There are many errors here. You're passing `function_ref` as the first template parameter to `static_method`, which should be `T`. You can't pass non-constexpr expressions as template arguments. The signature of `static_method` is wrong, it should be `Args` instead of `Args&&`. `Args&&` are not forwarding references. These are all tangled together and makes for a poor question. Please provide a [mre] with emphasis on _minimal_.

Comment: You are using an universal reference in your template `static_method`. But it will be parsed as an rvalue reference when you form a function pointer to it. So the signature of your typedef and function pointer don't match. But as others pointed out, that is just one of the issues...

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I want to pass around the wrapper function object as a `FunctionWrapper<int(int)>` for example. The key point here is that I don't want the underlying type of the object to appear. Casting to a void* was my approach to do this.

Comment: @NathanOliver yes `std::function` allows for type erasure, but I want something faster than `std::function` avoiding the possible heap allocations and virtual calls. By restricting the types of functions I'm using to only member functions, I should be able to avoid that overhead.

Comment: @PasserBy I've corrected the mistakes you spotted. The error hasn't changed. You said that "you can't pass non-constexpr expressions as template arguments" which template arguments are not constexpr?